# How to prevent millisecond rounding when importing csv in Python

Tags: python, pandas, time

The original time in csv is shown below in string

1/2/19 9:00:01.000

1/2/19 9:00:01.500

1/2/19 9:00:02.000

1/2/19 9:00:02.500

1/2/19 9:00:03.000

1/2/19 9:00:03.500

When I use `pd.read_csv` I notice that the milliseconds get rounded and doesn't maintain the 500 millisecond increement.

1/2/19 9:00:01.000

1/2/19 9:00:01.000

1/2/19 9:00:02.000

1/2/19 9:00:02.000

1/2/19 9:00:03.000

1/2/19 9:00:03.000

How do I prevent this? Is this normal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reading millisecond data into pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036028/reading-millisecond-data-into-pandas)

Comment: Please don't post text as image.

Answer (score 0):

It look like, at least in *Pandas 0.25*, even **nanoseconds** are preserved,
as long as you use *datetime64[ns]* data type.

I made such a test:

1. Input string:

   ```
   txt ='''Date,Amount
   2020-01-02 09:00:01.000200001,1
   2020-01-02 09:00:01.200030002,2
   2020-01-02 09:00:01.250004003,3'''
   ```
2. Read the DataFrame:

   ```
   df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), parse_dates=[0])
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
                              Date  Amount
   0 2020-01-02 09:00:01.000200001       1
   1 2020-01-02 09:00:01.200030002       2
   2 2020-01-02 09:00:01.250004003       3
   ```

   So as you can see, all 9 digits after the decimal point are in place.
3. Print microseconds:

   ```
   df.Date.dt.microsecond
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
   0       200
   1    200030
   2    250004
   Name: Date, dtype: int64
   ```
4. Print nanoseconds:

   ```
   df.Date.dt.nanosecond
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
   0    1
   1    2
   2    3
   Name: Date, dtype: int64
   ```

Maybe you use some older version of either *Python* or *Pandas*?
Try to upgrade them and repeat my test on your computer.

Comment: Python 3.7.3 I'm using this version